# I can't seem to call my method in my main correctly

Tags: python

Okay so, I'm making a superhero that lands the first punch, but I need to call my method with my main. I was told it was not in the right place, and I made this code awhile ago and can't seem to get it right now.

I tried making a new method and ended up naming it the same as the attribute.

```
class Superhero:

    def __init__(self, name = "", strengthPts = 0, staminaPts = 0, stylePts = 0, firstPunch = 0):
        self.name = name 
        self.strengthPts = strengthPts
        self.staminaPts = staminaPts
        self.stylePts = stylePts
        self.firstPunch = firstPunch

    def addStrengthPts(self, points):
        self.strengthPts = self.strengthPts + points

    def addstaminaPts(self, points):
        self.staminaPts = self.staminaPts + points

    def addstylePts(self, points):
        self.stylePts = self.stylePts + points

    def firstPunch(self):

        if(self.firstPunch == "-45 Points"):
            print("First Punch!")
        else:
            print("Miss")

def main():

    theHero = theHero("Eternal", "75", "50", "100", "-45 Points")

    print("Name: " + theHero.name)
    print("Strength Points: " + str(theHero.strengthPts))
    print("Stamina Points: " + str(theHero.staminaPts))
    print("Stle Points: " + str(theHero.stylePts))
    print("-----------------------------")
    print("Hit: " + str(theHero.firstPunch))

main()
```

The expected results are how much the punch deals which is "-45" but what I get is; "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'theHero' referenced before assignment on line 28" which I've never seen before.

Comment: What exactly do you think the second `theHero` is doing in `theHero = theHero("Eternal", "75", "50", "100", "-45 Points")`?

Comment: Hint: You probably need `theHero = Superhero(...)`. Otherwise, there *is* no `theHero` set, so how do you expect it to be called/invoked/etc?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. I found out I had one capitalized letter wrong which threw off the whole code. and fixed theHero and turned it to superHero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are not creating the object of the class `Superhero` instead you are calling the function that is actually a variable and that too is not assigned...and that's why you are getting the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'theHero' referenced before assignment on line 28`....

So the only thing you have to change is to make the `Superhero` object instead of calling the unassigned variable...

```
theHero = Superhero("Eternal", "75", "50", "100", "-45 Points")
#---------^^^^^^^^^-----------
# instead of
#-----------------------------
# theHero = theHero("Eternal", "75", "50", "100", "-45 Points")
#-----------×××××××-----------
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `class` in Python (in your case, it's SuperHero) and you have an `__init__` function, you need to initialize it before doing anything else.

If you want to create a new hero, let's say his name is Josh, you need to do it like this:

```
josh = SuperHero("Eternal", "75", "50", "100","-45 Points")
```

Josh is now a SuperHero object which you can play with:

```
josh.addstylePts(42)  # Example of using one of the class functions
```